# How can I set the print font-size in Textmate?

Tags: macos, printing, textmate

I've opened a text file in Textmate, and when I get ready to print it the font size is enormous. Not much fits on one page, even though it is just code with a fixed with.

I can copy and paste it into Word, but seems like there should just be an easier way to print with a smaller font size.

Attached is an image of what I see when I choose "print" - the font size is much too big. I like the font size in the editor, just not when printing. How can I change this?

[image]

Comment: What is the font size before trying to print?

Comment: TM Default - Monaco 12pt

Comment: It's on the [suggestions list](http://wiki.macromates.com/Suggestions/Preferences), I don't think you'll ever see the option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the font size in TextMate's menu bar.

[image]

This choice influences the font size on the printed page.

[image]

Reduce a few times to get print-optimized size, then reset again to continue editing.

---

It appears that if you resize your TextMate editing window to about 770 pixels height (measure with selection screenshot hotkey `Cmd-Shift-4`), this is the content that fits on a single page – at least on my machine.

Comment: This does no work for me. Changes the on-screen size, just not the print size.

Comment: @cwd Then something else is wrong on your computer. See the web page slhck has linked. *Font Size (different than screen)* and *Change font size for printing; a good screen size is always too large in print.* make it clear that they're linked.

Comment: I saw that page before I posted the question but thanks anyhow. What would be a good alternative program to use to print these types of pages?

Comment: @cwd I'm not a fan of printing things... would probably make a good question though, "How to best print source code on OS X with line numbers, syntax highlighting, header/footer information, etc." if it hasn't been asked before.

Comment: It's not just about source code. I use TextMate as a notepad when summering up information for offline usage (and have to c'n'p some technical words I don't really feel like writing down myself).
In my case (just plaintext, space and/or tab formatted) I just fired up TextEdit (OS X's default editor I think) and pasted text in their for printing. Faster than word but still a workaround. Result is satisfying though. Edit: 70% satisfying, tabs got messed up :C

Answer (score 1):

Changing the font size didn't work for me either.

However if you do `File > Page Setup` and change the **scale** of the page, you can achieve the same result.